Проект в django. Миксин для любых сущностей
Есть вот такой простой миксин:
class UniqueNameErrorMixin:
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if Status.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Статус с таким именем уже существует.')
        return name

Как сделать его универсальным, чтобы его можно было просто импортировать и использовать для других сущностей?

Но зачем, если можно просто повесить unique=True на нужное поле модели?

@andreymal это все ради вывода ошибки, чтобы она адекватно отображалась "Статус с таким именем уже существует", а по умолчанию что то вроде Status c таким имя уже существуют.
